# unique_together and M2M field

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have the following Model:

```
class CodeSynonyms(models.Model):
    code = models.ForeignKey(Codes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    websites = models.ManyToManyField(Websites)
    synonym = models.Charfield(max_length=10)
```

The idea is that Websites use the Synonyms for specific Codes. One Website can't have few Synonyms for a Code; various Websites can share the same Synonym for specific Code. The following won't work:

```
class Meta:
unique together = ('code', 'websites')
```

" 'unique_together' refers to a ManyToManyField 'websites', but ManyToManyFields are not permitted in 'unique_together' "

Is there a way to solve this keeping the M2M relation? It would be handy to have it

Comment: 'cant have few synonyms'?

Comment: A Website can have only one Synonym for a Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `through` in `ManyToManyField`and connect your many to many relations through custom  intermediate table. then add `unique_together` there:

```
class CodeSynonyms(models.Model):
    # add through field
    websites = models.ManyToManyField(Websites, through='WebsiteCode')
    synonym = models.Charfield(max_length=10)

class WebsiteCode(models.Model):
    code_synonym = models.ForeignKey(CodeSynonyms, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    website = models.ForeignKey(Websites, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.ForeignKey(Codes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique together = ('code', 'website')
```